# Replace all values in dataframe with an ifelse and %in% operator

Tags: r

I'd like to recode all the values in a data set with an ifelse statement, using %in% as the operator. Here is some example data.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( matrix(sample(1:5,20,TRUE), 4, 5) )
df 

> df 
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3  3  2  3  1
2  3  5  3  1  5
3  2  4  5  4  3
4  2  1  3  1  2
```

I know I can convert values of 4 or 5 to value 1, and rest to zero with this code

```
df_result <- ifelse( df == 4 | df == 5 , 1, 0) 

> df_result
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0
[2,]  0  1  0  0  1
[3,]  0  1  1  1  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0  0
```

However I would prefer to use **%in% c(4,5)** like this, but it doesn't work

```
ifelse( df %in% c(4,5) , 1, 0) 
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

It just reports a string of numbers. Is it possible to tweak it to make this work?
The reason I want to use %in% operator is that the c(4,5) part can have a large number of items making it impractical to use OR repeatedly. Any method can be used as long as I can represent the **c(4,5)** in the code that way.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df_result <- ifelse( df == 4 | df == 5 , 1, 0)` looks as good as the answers below.  `%in%` operates on vectors, but you want it to work element-by-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some base R options:

This maps a function over the columns in your data frame. Specifically the function tests if each element of the column is in your vector. This returns boolean values, which are then converted to `0` and `1` with `as.numeric`. The output of `Map` is a list, so `data.frame` converts it back to a data frame.

```
data.frame(Map(function(x) as.numeric(x %in% c(4,5)), df))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  1  0
4  1  1  0  1  0
```

Similarly,

```
data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) as.numeric(x %in% c(4,5))))
```

Alternatively, you can test the data frame against each vector element and then combine the results:

```
data.frame(Reduce(`+`, lapply(c(4,5), `==`, df)))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  1  0
4  1  1  0  1  0
```

`lapply` will test `df == 4` and store that boolean matrix in a list element. Then it will test `df == 5` and again store that in a list element. `Reduce` then sums these two list elements element-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tidyverse` and magrittr's [placeholder dot](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) we can make a function and apply it to each column of the data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~ifelse(. %in% c(4,5), 1, 0)))

 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  1
3  0  1  1  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

However, be careful when you have numeric columns and integer columns as using `%in%` can sometimes be misleading:

```
c(1, 1L) %in% c(1, 1.1)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```